# How to convert $\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\beta x^2}$ or $\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\alpha \beta x^2}$ to a closed form?

Tags: power-series

How to solve $\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\beta x^2}$ or 
 $\sum_{x=0}^n e^{-\alpha \beta x^2}$  ??

where $\alpha$ = 1/($n$+1) and $\beta$ is just a variable.

Can I find it?

Comment: what does $i$ have got to do with the expression inside the summation? Moreover there is nothing to "solve" here, are you interested in finding the sum?

Comment: As written, you have $(n+1)e^{-x^2}$

Comment: There was a mistake. It is edited. $i$ is edited to $x$

Comment: Generally does not have a nice closed form (look up theta function) but you can bound it using an integral pretty acurately

Comment: Care to fix the typos.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't find it on closed form.

Some have closed form for $n=\infty$.
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-j^2}= \frac12\left(1+\vartheta_3\left(0\;,\;\frac{1}{e} \right) \right)$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-\beta j^2}= \frac12\left(1+\vartheta_3\left(0\;,\;e^{-\beta} \right) \right)\qquad \beta>0.$$
About the Jacobi theta functions : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html